# How do I validate the length of a title in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails right now and one of the exercises that I am trying to figure out is how to validate the title such that it has more than 10 characters. The hint says to use the **:length** method(?) in ruby.

So far I've tried:

```
validates :title.length, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 10}
```

and

```
validates :title, length: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 10}
```

both of which has given me errors.

What should I do here?

Another quick question, what is the difference when the colon(:) is on the left and right? for the length, it's on the left (**:length**), but for numericality, it's on the right (**numericality:**) I'm thinking if it's on the left it's a variable, and if it's on the right it's a method. Not sure if that's a good way to think of it.

Comment: Technically that's called an *option* in this particular context. `validates` is the method.

Comment: And also `numericality` can't be used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
validates :title, length: {minimum: 10}
```

To your second question:

```
key: value
```

is a hash syntax, which means the same as

```
:key => value
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're being told to do it that way. [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) is pretty specific:

```
validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
```